# Sequelize aggregation self-join

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, aggregation

Versions:

```
node: 10.13.0,
sequelize: 5.16.0,
MySQL: 5.7,
```

Models:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Bidder = sequelize.define('Bidder', {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    identifier: DataTypes.STRING,
  });
  Bidder.associate = models => {
    Bidder.hasMany(models.Bid);
    Bidder.addScope('withBids', {
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Bid,
        },
      ],
    });
  };
  return Bidder;
};

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Sku = sequelize.define('Sku', {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    amount: DataType.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
  });
  Sku.associate = models => {
    Sku.hasMany(models.Bid);
    Sku.addScope('withBids', {
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Bid,
        },
      ],
    });
  };
  return Sku;
};

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Bid = sequelize.define('Bid', {
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    identifier: DataTypes.STRING,
  });
  Bid.associate = models => {
    Bid.belongsTo(models.Sku);
    Bid.addScope('withSku', {
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Sku,
        },
      ],
    });

    Bid.belongsTo(models.Bidder);
    Bid.addScope('withBidder', {
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Bidder,
        },
      ],
    });
  };
  return Bid;
};
```

I am looking to query the Bids table for the list of Skus which a Bidder has bid on, their highest bid, and the highest bid overall.

In MySQL, I can use the following query to get this information:

```sql
SELECT 
  b.`uuid`, b.`skuUuid`, amount, highest_bid
FROM 
  Bids b 
  JOIN 
    (
      SELECT skuUuid, max(amount) as "max_bid" 
      FROM Bids 
      WHERE Bids.`bidderUuid` = "SOME_UUID" 
      GROUP BY skuUUid
    ) mb 
    ON b.`skuUuid` = mb.`skuUuid` AND b.`amount` = mb.`max_bid` 
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT skuUuid, max(amount) as "highest_bid" 
      FROM Bids 
      GROUP BY skuUuid
    ) hb
    ON b.`skuUuid` = hb.`skuUuid`
WHERE 
    b.`bidderUuid` = "SOME_UUID"
```

Given a specific Bidder UUID, the previous query would return the list of each unique Sku the Bidder bid on they have bid on, their maximum bid amount (along with the associated uuid of the bid; they may have placed multiple bids on the same Sku during competition with another Bidder), and the overall maximum bid of the Sku.

```
|---------|---------|--------|-------------|
| uuid    | skuUuid | amount | highest_bid |
|---------|---------|--------|-------------|
| buuid-1 | suuid-1 | 50     | 70          |
| buuid-2 | suuid-4 | 150    | 150         |
| buuid-3 | suuid-6 | 5      | 40          |
| buuid-8 | suuid-8 | 55     | 55          |
|---------|---------|--------|-------------|
```

While I'm comfortable using Sequelize to query the database for rows, the aggregation and complexity in the `JOIN`ing of the subqueries has me stumped.

The highest bid amount can be fetched using:

```js
const highBids = await Bid.findAll({
  attributes: ['skuUuid', [fn('max', col('amount')), 'max_bid']],
  group: ['skuUuid'],
});
```

...and the highest bid amount by the specific Bidder can be found using:

```js
const myBids = await Bid.findAll({
  where: {
    bidderUuid: 'SOME_UUID',
  },
  attributes: ['skuUuid', [fn('max', col('amount')), 'max_bid']],
  group: ['skuUuid'],
});
```

...finally, the UUID of the specific Bids can be found using:

```js
const {rows: bids, count} = await Bid.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: ['uuid'],
  where: {
    bidderUuid: 'SOME_UUID',
  },
  include: [
    // This query should be joined with myBids in order to return the UUID of the highest bids by the specific user
    // This query should be joined with highBids (limited to the Skus which the specified Bidder has bid on) in order to infer whether the Bidder is "winning" that auction
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do include/association only when there is relation b/w table, either it's self or with others

So in your case, you can't do that by `sequelize.query` :

```
sequelize.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `users`", // <---- Replace it with your Query
                { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result); //<--- Check the result
})
```